# How to add extra space to the edges of the text of a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` with the text "Hello".

I'm using autolayout, I didn't set any width or height for the button as I want it to be as big as its content as this one might change.

And I want to add a gap of let's say 10 pts on each edge.

All the topics I have found so far talk about adding some gap by using `titleEdgeInsets`. I cannot use it as it will just move the title but won't resize the actual button.

Is there an easier way than: 
- get the text, calculate the size of its bounding rectangle
- set the button's frame based on the previous size + any gap
- play with `titleEdgeInsets`

?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add gaps outside the button then just wrap it inside a custom view, which implements systemLayoutSizeFittingSize function and returns the value returned from UIButton.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize + gap.

To add the gaps inside the button, subclass UIButton and override systemLayoutSizeFittingSize.